# VSTS - How to build solution in different team project?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I just fired up VSTS after a while away from it.  Working on other projects.

Microsoft seems to have changed the build definition UI and now I cannot build solutions located in other team projects.

MS has Repositories listed, but only the current team project.

If I am in a build definition saved in Team Project A, how do I now map sources to a solution in Team Project B?

This used to be easy until this new build editor was released...

Comment: Would connecting to a "Remote repo" in the "Get sources" step help you with your problem? Do you have a GIT repo in the other Team Project?

Comment: No, we do not use GIT.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TFVC repository, you can specify the path of other team project in Workspace mappings, then the source in other team project would be downloaded too.

[image]

If you are using git repository, the better way is using submodule.

Comment: Not using GIT.  And this won't work for CI triggers.  IN there you MUST use the same Repo as your trigger mapping only.

Answer (score 0):

- **If the solution in team proejct B is not related with solution in team project A**, you can go to projects page https://account.visualstudio.com/_projects (or go to the page from team project A directly by clicking the icon in the top left corner) to select team project B.

  [image]

  Then in the Build tab, create/edit your build definition and then queue your build.
- **If you want to build the solution in team project A with the solution in team project B together**, you can add the solution in team project B as [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) for the repo in team project A (if you used git as VCS). Else you checkin the code from team project B to team project A (if you use TFVC as VCS).

**BTW:** in a build definition, it does only list the repositories in current team project. Even for the old build definition UI/editor, it also only list the repositories for the current team project.

Comment: Not using GIT.  I can add the path in the workspace mappings, but the CI trigger does NOT allow you to specify any VCS path.. you MUST select a path in the same repo.   What on earth is MS thinking?

Comment: In TFS 2012 - 13 you could pick ANY team project in the whole collection.  I think even TFS 2015 supported that.  MS has decided to lock things down considerably.  Particularly in the CI triggers where you MUST use the same repo only.  The only solution I can come up with now is to move ALL the source code into ONE team project. Yuk.

Comment: I really don't see the point in offering cross-TeamProject mappings if your CI triggers can't do the same... what's the point?